# Simple recurrence relation in fortran and matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, recurrence, polynomials

I wrote the following program in fortran

```
    implicit real*16 (a-h,o-z)
    implicit integer*8 (i-n)
    
    parameter (nnmax=130000, nbarmax = nnmax/2,ipmax =5)
    parameter (nulatmax=5000)
    dimension doef(0:nbarmax)
    dimension coef(0:ipmax,0:nnmax)
    dimension aux(-1:nnmax)
    
    ip = 2
    anzn = 3
    
    coef = 0.q0 !-->zera todos os coeficientes
    
    alamb = 1.q0
    
    !Initial conditions
    do i1 =0,ip
       coef(i1,0) = 1.q0
    end do
!   write(*,*)'linha 271'
    aux(-1) = 0.q0
!   iteracao
    
    M = 30
    do nn =1, M
      nnbar = (nn+ip)/(ip+1)
      natual =mod(nn +2*(ip+1)-1,ip+1)
      nanter =mod(nn +2*(ip+1)-2,ip+1)
      nfirst =mod(nn +2*(ip+1)-(ip+2),ip+1)
      do i2=0,nnbar
        aux(i2) = coef(natual,i2)
      end do
      
      do i2=0,nnbar
        coef(natual,i2) = coef(nanter,i2) -(alamb**anzn)*aux(i2-1)
        doef(i2) = coef(natual,i2)
        write(511,*) nn,doef(i2)
      enddo
    enddo
          
endprogram
```

that solve the below recurrence relation

**P**<sub>m+3</sub>(**x**) = **P**<sub>m+2</sub>(**x**) - **x** * **P**<sub>m</sub>(**x**), with **m**>=0

and initial conditions **P<sub>0</sub>**= 1, **P<sub>1</sub>**= 1-**x**, **P<sub>2</sub>**= 1-2**x**.

Now, I'm try to find all roots of this polynomials. I know this is easily done in matlab using **roots(X)** function, where **X** is a column vector of polynomial coefficients.

Therefore I would like to write my above routine which calculates the polynomial coefficients in matlab. Thanks if anyone can help me.

Comment: One can usually simply load the source code of a simple Fortran program (such as the one shown here) into a Matlab session (ignore the entity declarations) and deal with the handful of problems which occur, such as replacing ` do I = 1,n` with `for i = 1:n`.  The syntax is pretty similar and in Matlab, for a first attempt, one doesn't need to define entities before using them.

Comment: How can I add a vector of type c(x,y) in matlab? When I input c(i1;0) in matlab it doesn't like.

Comment: for example, the initial condition `for i1=0,ip   coef(i1;0) = 1 end` doens't work in matlab.